# Relation between .then and deferObj.resolve() of promise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am finding it hard to understand few concepts of promise in angularjs. I understand what is it and when to use it and that $q.defer creates a promise object which has  methods like resolve(), reject() I know there functionalities but what I am not able to understand is when to use it with .then function in some cases we use it and in some cases we don't .

[link1](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/) [link2](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) [link3](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises)

I went through many links like above but still not getting , maybe I am understanding it all wrong . But anyone please explain when to put the .resolve method in .then function or if my understanding is totally wrong kindly correct me before downvoting as really did try to understand it on my own before posting the question over here.

Comment: _"explain when to put the .resolve method in .then function"_ `.then()` should follow `.resolve()`. Can you include an example of `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: You typically put the `.resolve()` in the `.then()` when you want the calling function to know the promise has been fulfilled

Comment: @Ladmerc but in with $http we just use .then and not the resolve method in it . could you please explain why ?

Comment: Because the `.then()` of `$http` typically means your promise has been resolved. Unless of course you have another promise to resolve within the `.then()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Promise is an object that can be passed or returned and holds reference to the outcome of asynchronous behavior. In Angular they are created through the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

`$q.defer()` creates an object that has special methods, among then `resolve()` and `reject()`. The `resolve()` method indicates successful completion of the execution and wraps the data for the promise to return later on. If something goes wrong the `reject()` method should be called, sending an error object or error message.

This function should have a caller, and this caller should capture a reference to the promise object.

Here is where the `then()` method can be called to obtain the results or handle the errors according to the case. Notice that the `then()` method takes 2 arguments, which are the functions that are going to be executed in case of success, or in case of error.

In [link3](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises) you can see one part of the code has the definition of the asynchronous function named `getData` and later there is the call to `then()` to obtain the results, this call is made by the caller of the asynchronous function `getData`.

In [link2](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) Controller **FatherCtrl** is the one calling `then()` to process the response of the Service **SonService**. It may be confusing that there is also a call to the `then()` method in the **SonService**, but this is to obtain the result of the HTTP GET call, as the comment properly explains it:

```
// the $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service
// so it returns a promise for us by default
```

In this example you only see the `then()` part because the `get()` method of the `$http` service is an asyncronous function that upon completion is making the `resolve()` or `reject()` method call accordingly.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise.

And again, what is a promise? Check the beginning of this answer. The code for the methods of the `$http` service have been written already. When any of this methods are called, and they finish they call either `resolve()` or `reject()`. The developer has to write code accordingly to read this outcome. (Yes, this is the `then()` that you we were talking about in the comments ;) ).

Comment: but  with $http we just use .then and not the resolve method in it . could you please explain why ?

Comment: So you mean $http cals $q.defer.resolve () automatically / implicitly ?

Comment: Updated answer @titlu.

Answer (score 0):

> please explain when to put the .resolve method in .then function

[**Absolutely never**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

If you refer to the example from [your second link](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html), that's just an antipattern and should not be used.